# how to remove Preferences, Statistics, & Comments menus in MyBlog extention in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5.4 for my web project and I am using MyBlog extension for the blogging feature for my web. now, I want to remove the 3 menu buttons ( Preferences, Statistics, & Comments) in MyBlog. i look over in the MyBlog Configuration but there is no config there on how to remove it.

do anyone can help me on where can i remove this menus using configuration?

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be an idea to contact the developers of this extension. Seeing as its a commercial extension, you will be very lucky to get answer. If the extension used "views" folder rather than admin.extensionname.html.php then I would have thought the code you are looking for will be in the file in the specific view folder. Sorry, its not much to go.